# Inequalities - When to know if some expression are below/above 0?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**Inequality:**
$$\sqrt{9x^2 - 16} > 3x + 1$$

I was thinking of...

1. Squaring the whole inequality
2. Move them between the > sign, which eventually I get (x < -17/6)

However on my **answer sheet:**

Left hand side - $9x^2 - 16 > 0 \implies x > 4/3 \text{ and } x < -4/3$

Right hand side - $3x + 1 > 0 \implies x > -1/3$

**Question:**

1. How do we know $9x^2 - 16$ and $3x + 1$ is above $0$?
2. When do we need to have 2 answers (LHS and RHS answer)

Answer (score 2):

Let's apply your idea:

$$\sqrt{9x^2-16}>3x+1\implies 9x^2-16>9x^2+6x+1\implies6x<-17\implies$$

$$\implies x<-\frac{17}6\cong- 2.833\;\;\;(**)$$

But the *real* square root is defined iff

$$9x^2-16\ge0\iff x^2\ge\frac{16}9\iff |x|\ge\frac43\cong1.33$$

Thus, the answer in $(**)$  is within the allowed values for $\;x\;$ ...and then the left side is **always** non-negative, whereas the right side is negative in that ray...

Comment: Small typo ! $-2.833$

Comment: Good catch, @ClaudeLeibovici. Mercy beaucoup.

Comment: Lo mejor es que soy como ciego ! Un abrazo.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.

Very sorry, but I still don't understand how do we know if (9x^2−16) and (3x + 1) are above 0?

Comment: Well, the square root **always** is non-negative, by definition (we always choose the non-negative square root), but in the found inequality's solution set, the right hand is **always** negative...

Comment: @kimnod It's not that we know they are positive. It is that the problem is interesting _only if_ they are positive. The left-hand side, with square root, can only ever be positive or undefined. Thus if the right-hand side is negative, it's no contest, the left hand side is largest (if it's defined), thus we are interested in when $3x + 1$ is positive. We want to know where $9x^2 + 16$ is positive because that's where the square root is defined, thus we are interested in where $9x^2 - 16$ is positive.